# How to delete Phonegap project from command line

Tags: cordova

Anyone know how to delete a Phonegap project from the command line?

I'm using version 3.1.0-0.15.0

Created a project using:

$ phonegap create etc...

I screwed up some settings, so I now want to delete it cleanly and then start over.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's the same way as deleting a folder in any directory, using the **rmdir** or **rm** command. You can simply go to the folder location and delete the directory entirely.

You can read more here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/delete-or-remove-a-directory-linux-command/

Comment: I tried removing the directories, but then when I tried to recreate the project I got error messages saying that the project already existed.

Comment: Although I just did a create/rmdir/create and it worked - weird.
Thanks for the reply - rubber-duck moment!